# Why do some of my friends have yellow names, and how do I get it?

Tags: steam

[image]

Some of the friends on my list have yellow names now.  I can't seem to find out if it has to do with their status or something new added in the options, but I can't recall having seen this earlier this year.

What do these yellow names represent, and how do I get them?

Comment: Why didn't you just asked on of your friends who has a golden profile? Btw. I hope they keep this feature and make it avilable even after this event...

Comment: @Mischa It probably won't stay as it says in the description, maybe if you level it up a few times?

Comment: Nice example of gamification of the shopping experience.

Comment: @Wouter I do not mean that one should keep the golden profile after the purchase. What I mean is another posibility to get a golden profile (for a limited amount of time). Oh btw. You can only level it up once... And then it will stay until 06. March.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One of the [Lunar New Year rewards](https://store.steampowered.com/lny2019/rewards) introduced in this year's Lunar New Year Steam sale lets you turn your Steam profile golden for a limited time. Users with golden profiles also have their name displayed in gold, and a gold border around their profile avatar.

Comment: Note, limited time is 1 month for 4k, 1 year for 12k

Comment: Spend money by buying games* - You don't need to buy $100 in tokens, you need to buy $100 in games and then you get the tokens.  Also note that if you refund one of the games you buy, you lose the tokens/golden border (I tried it, hehe)

Comment: Als note that with the start of the sale each user gets a certain amount of free tokens based on their previous purchases. "The initial number of tokens you received is based on previous purchases made on your account.
". This makes it each for some user to buy the golden profile, since they may already start with 4k+ tokens.

Comment: @L_Church no, it's until 2019-02-12 for 4k, 2019-03-06 for 12k.

Comment: Note that you need to own the 1 month one before you can get the 12month one, so technically 12 months is 16k

Comment: and i thought it was a year... lol nah